# Linq Extension to Return Grouped results

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following code, and trying to avoid **code duplication**
What I'd like to do is have a Custom **Extension method** say called "SelectGrouped"

that would accept a "Shift" object, and return the anonymous type (not sure if that possible)

```
var groupedFillingsCurrentShift = currentShift.FilingMeasurements
                    .Where(f => TimeSpan.Parse(f.MeasurementTime.MeasurementTime) == ShiftEnd)
                    .GroupBy(f => new { f.Medium, f.MeasurementTime })
                    .Select(t => new { t.Key.Medium, t.Key.MeasurementTime, VolumeInTanks = t.Sum(s => s.Filing) })
                    .ToList();


if (previousShift != null)
{
    var groupedFillingsPreviousShift = previousShift.FilingMeasurements
        .Where(f => TimeSpan.Parse(f.MeasurementTime.MeasurementTime) == previousShift.ShiftEnd)
        .GroupBy(f => new { f.Medium, f.MeasurementTime })
        .Select(t => new { t.Key.Medium, t.Key.MeasurementTime, VolumeInTanks = t.Sum(s => s.Filing) })
        .ToList();
```

What I'd like to achieve is to have it look like so

```
var groupedResultCurrentShift = 
   currentShift.SelectGrouped(t=>t.Medium, t.MeasurementTime, t.VolumenInTanks);

var groupedResultPreviousShift = 
   previousShift.SelectGrouped(t=>t.Medium, t.MeasurementTime, t.VolumenInTanks);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want can't be done in its current form.

First off, the variable `t` only has value in the lambda. The commas separate parameters, and so `t` loses its scope for the other parameters.

Second and more importantly, anonymous types are locally scoped by definition, because you have to use "var" to imply the type of a variable that holds them. You can't pass them in as parameters nor return them as return values (well, technically you can using `dynamic`, but let's not go there, *please*).

If you were to define a named type that could be used to hold the final form of the projected data, this would work:

```
internal class VolumeData
{
   public string Medium;
   public DateTime MeasurementTime;
   public decimal VolumeInTanks;
}

public static List<VolumeData> GetVolumeData(this Shift shift)
{
   return shift.FilingMeasurements
               .Where(f => TimeSpan.Parse(f.MeasurementTime.MeasurementTime) == ShiftEnd)
               .GroupBy(f => new { f.Medium, f.MeasurementTime })
               .Select(t => new VolumeData{ 
                                Medium = t.Key.Medium, 
                                MeasurementTime = t.Key.MeasurementTime, 
                                VolumeInTanks = t.Sum(s => s.Filing) })
               .ToList();
}

...

var groupedFillingsCurrentShift = currentShift.GetVolumeData();


if (previousShift != null)
    var groupedFillingsPreviousShift = previousShift.GetVolumeData();
```

Comment: Thanx. That was my suspicion too, that I'd need to use dynamic to implement this. (or hard type a class).

Answer (score 0):

```
var groupedResultCurrentShift = 
 currentShift.SelectGrouped(t=>t.Medium, t.MeasurementTime, t.VolumenInTanks);
```

Makes no sense, because the `t` of the second and third clause isn't defined, and `VolumenInTanks` relates to a property that you haven't created yet.

We also have a problem, in that the `Select` in your query relates to an anonymous object defined earlier in the same scope. This prevents us from defining a method that lets us pass in a lambda defining what should be selected.

However:

```
currentShift.FilingMeasurements
                .Where(f => TimeSpan.Parse(f.MeasurementTime.MeasurementTime) == ShiftEnd)
                .GroupBy(f => new { f.Medium, f.MeasurementTime })
                .Select(t => new { t.Key.Medium, t.Key.MeasurementTime, VolumeInTanks = t.Sum(s => s.Filing) })
                .ToList();
```

is equivalent to;

```
currentShift.FilingMeasurements
                .Where(f => TimeSpan.Parse(f.MeasurementTime.MeasurementTime) == ShiftEnd)
                .GroupBy(f => new { f.Medium, f.MeasurementTime }, s => s.Filing)
                .Select(t => new { t.Key.Medium, t.Key.MeasurementTime, VolumeInTanks = t.Sum() })
                .ToList();
```

Now, this still isn't quite there, but let's consider that we get the same information from:

```
currentShift.FilingMeasurements
                .Where(f => TimeSpan.Parse(f.MeasurementTime.MeasurementTime) == ShiftEnd)
                .GroupBy(f => new { f.Medium, f.MeasurementTime }, s => s.Filing)
                .Select(t => new { t.Key, VolumeInTanks = t.Sum() })
                .ToList();
```

So. If you'd be willing to have to do `item.Key.Medium` rather than `item.Medium`, then we're in business:

We need a return type, so we'll create one:

```
public class GroupedCount<T>
{
  public<T> Key{get;set;}
  public int Count{get;set;}//bit more of a general-purpose name than VolumeInTanks
}
```

Now, create our method:

```
public static List<GroupedCount<TKey>> ToGroupedCounts<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> pred, Func<TSource, TKey> keyGen, Func<TSource, int> tallyGen)
{
    currentShift.FilingMeasurements
                .Where(pred)
                .GroupBy(keyGen, tallyGen)
                .Select(t => new GroupedCount<TKey>{ Key = t.Key, Count = t.Sum() })
                .ToList();
}
```

We can now call:

```
currentShift.ToGroupedCounts(
  f => TimeSpan.Parse(f.MeasurementTime.MeasurementTime) == ShiftEnd,
  f => new { f.Medium, f.MeasurementTime },
  s => s.Filing
);
```

Since we want this to be general purpose, and `ToList()` shouldn't be called unless it's definitely needed in the specific case, it makes more sense to return an IQueryable:

```
public static IQueryable<GroupedCount<TKey>> ToGroupedCounts<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> pred, Func<TSource, TKey> keyGen, Func<TSource, int> tallyGen)
{
    currentShift.FilingMeasurements
                .Where(pred)
                .GroupBy(keyGen, tallyGen)
                .Select(t => new GroupedCount<TKey>{ Key = t.Key, Count = t.Sum() });
}
```

Comment: Nice :) Not really sure what You did there with the <T> Key.

Comment: That's whatever your key type that goes along with the count is, so in the case of the call it's an anonymous object with `Medium`  and `MeasurementTime` properties. It's created based on the second parameter (the first filters out those you don't want, and the third says what property you are summing).